# linux launch script /etc/init with a specific user

Tags: su, services, upstart

I've created a script in /etc/init/mms-agent.conf :

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

exec /usr/bin/env python /home/mms/mms-agent/agent.py >> /home/mms/agent.log 2>&1
```

service mms-agent start/stop work fine, but i'd like to start this service with the user "mms"

When I try to change the script as following :

```
exec su mms -c "/usr/bin/env python /home/mms/mms-agent/agent.py >> /home/mms/agent.log 2>&1"
```

I get 3 process running instead of 1 expected (su, bash + my python script):

```
mms       8864  0.0  0.2  37816  1332 ?        Ss   22:30   0:00 su mms -c /usr/bin/env python /home/mms/mms-agent/agent.py >> /home/mms/agent.log 2>&1
mms       8865  0.0  0.2  11452  1196 ?        S    22:30   0:00 bash -c /usr/bin/env python /home/mms/mms-agent/agent.py >> /home/mms/agent.log 2>&1
mms       8866  4.0  1.8  54672 10640 ?        Sl   22:30   0:00 python /home/mms/mms-agent/agent.py
```

What does that mean ?

What is the best way to start a script with a user different than root ?

Thanks

PS :

```
exec start-stop-daemon --start -u mms --exec "/usr/bin/env python /home/mms/mms-agent/agent.py"
```

doesn't work, I got no error but the process isn't started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you exec `su`, the shell is replaced with the `su` process.  `su` then forks and execs `bash`.  `bash` sets up the output redirection and then forks and execs `env`.  `env` searches PATH, finds `python` and execs it.  So you're left with three processes, 1) `su`, waiting for `bash` to exit, 2) `bash`, waiting for `python` (previously `env`) to exit, and 3) `python`, which is busily running your script.

There is nothing wrong with this.  `su` is the Unix time-honored way to temporarily switch users, so that's what you should be using.  Similarly, the way to run a command line is to use a shell, so `su` runs `bash` and lets `bash` handle it.  Again, this follows the general Unix toolbox approach, letting the shell do what the shell is good at, and not reinventing shell command line and PATH search functionality in another application.

Also, since `bash` is already doing the PATH search, you can drop the use of `env` and invoke `python` directly.

Answer (score 3):

See [Run a Job as a Different User](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#run-a-job-as-a-different-user) in the Upstart manual. Using `start-stop-daemon` is the recommended method.

You just made a small mistake: you passed the whole command line where `start-stop-daemon` expects the path to the executable. Pass the arguments separately.

Another problem with your invocation is that you're telling `start-stop-daemon` to consider any Python process to be an instance of your service. That might result in it killing other unrelated Python processes. To ensure only one instance of your service runs, use a pidfile.

```
exec start-stop-daemon --start -c mms -u mms -m -p /var/run/mms-agent.pid \
                       --startas /usr/bin/env -- python /home/mms/mms-agent/agent.py
```

Comment: humm can't get it launch, even with exec start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile /var/run/mms-agent.pid -m -c mms  --exec python /home/mms/mms-agent/agent.py -- run  > /home/mms/agent.log 2>&1

Comment: Your path to the executable files need to come after the --.  Also, you should use the --exec flag

i.e.

start-stop-daemon --start -u mms -m -p /var/run/mms-agent.pid --exec python -- /home/mms/mms-agent/agent.py

Comment: @Quentin Does anything appear in a log file in `/var/log`? If the launch fail, you should have a log message.

Comment: right, the path to python was missing, I added /usr/bin/env (or /usr/bin/python2.7), but now the following lauch the script as root, no with my mms user... Any idea ? exec start-stop-daemon --start -u mms -m -p /var/run/mms-agent.pid --exec /usr/bin/env python -- /home/mms/mms-agent/agent.py

Comment: ok, adding -c mms make it start with the mms user. Not sure to understand the difference between -c and -u.

Comment: @Quentin `-c` tells `start-stop-daemon` to change to the specified user, I should have used it from the start. `-u` tells `start-stop-daemon` to check for an existing process running as that user. The options are separate because some daemons change users after starting.

Answer (score 1):

You get three processes because you're running su, which starts a shell to run the python process.

There are several ways to convince the "extra" two processes that they can exit, for example you can have the python script fork and exec, or you can have the command you execute with su background itself.